# Is it safe to rely on javafx.util.Callback?

Tags: java, javafx, callback

Is it safe to use the `javafx.util.Callback` on a server machine? As I understand, and I may be wrong, not all JavaFX components are available on a server installation where graphics arent available.

Should I create my own callback interface, or just use one from javafx?

Comment: Why not use [`java.util.function.Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html), which basically provides an identical API, and is truly part of the core API?

Comment: wasnt aware of it. you should put that as answer

Answer (score 0):

At first, I didn’t like using it either, because this interface was losing quality in my code. I no longer had self-explaining interface names. But in the end, I realized that the advantages overweigh the lack of quality. The advantages being:

- We end up writing less code. No specialized interface, no default implementations.
- The developer using the API does not have to remember different factories, instead, he can focus on the object that he wants to create and the parameters that are available to him.
- The Callback interface is a functional interface. We can use Lambda expressions, which makes the code more elegant and we once again have to write less code.

Therefore I would suggest using `javafx.util.Callback` instead of custom one

Comment: if the OS has no graphics device javaFX is missing from java. better to just write your own callback interface

Comment: `java.util.function.Function` provides the same API and is part of the core API. So it has all the advantages listed here but doesn't assume a JVM that has access to JavaFX libraries.